# Not able to get texts from table using xpath and java script executor

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Want to get text 48630 and 49928  which is under tab div and a in the first td of each tr.
Need only one xpath for this to get text from div or a according data exists in table.

```
     <table class="x-grid-table x-grid-table-resizer" cellspacing="0"     cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 1505px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="x-grid-header-row">
    <tr class="x-grid-row">
    <td id="ext-gen1289" class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1126 x-grid-cell-first">
       <div id="ext-gen1290" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable"     style="background-color: #BECFE1;; text-align: left;"     unselectable="on">48630</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1127 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1128 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1129 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1130 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1131 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1132 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1133 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1134 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1135 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1136 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1137 x-grid-cell-last">
    </tr>
    <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-alt">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1126 x-grid-cell-first">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="background-color:#EAEEF5;; text-align: left;" unselectable="on">
            <a        onclick="Travel.common.Common.viewport.items.getAt(1).OManagePanel.loadSubscript    ion()" href="#">49928</a>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1127 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1128 ">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1129 ">
```

Tried following options of xpaths-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/(div|div/a)")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div | //table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div/a")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div) | (//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div/a)"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/child::node()[contains(text(), *)]")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td[1]/descendant::*[contains(text(), *)]")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td[1]/descendant::node()[contains(text(), *)]")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/(div|div/a)")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div | //table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div/a")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div) | (//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div/a)"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/child::node()[contains(text(), *)]")); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td[1]/descendant::*[contains(text(), *)]"));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td[1]/descendant::node()[contains(text(), *)]")); 


text = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);
            allSetSubscriptions2.add(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like:

```
//div[@id='ext-gen1290']/text()
```

or if `id` is dyanamic. You can use:

```
//td[contains(@class,'x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-')]//a/text()
```

Comment: use something like `//td[contains(@class,'x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-')]//a/text()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
//div[@class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable"]/a');
```

Comment: tried following code but else loop does not work. Giving exception. Not able to get text of div tag.

Comment: `boolean        text1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div/a[contains(     text(), *)]")).isDisplayed();
    if (text1==true){    element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div/a"));
    text = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);
       allSetSubscriptions2.add(text);
       }else{
    element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div"));
    text = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);
    allSetSubscriptions2.add(text);
        }System.out.println(allSetSubscriptions2);`

Comment: also tried following but values of div tag are coming null.
 `try{
    element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div/a"));
       text = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);
          System.out.println(text);
    allSetSubscriptions2.add(text);
   }catch(Exception e){
          element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr["+i+"]/td/div"));
       text = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", element);
           System.out.println(text);
    allSetSubscriptions2.add(text);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath: //div[@unselectable="on"]
```

You can use the above xpath and find elements matching the unselectable attribute, and you can iterate over and store the texts in an array.

Something like,

```
List<String> text_item= new ArrayList<String>();
allElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath('//div[@unselectable="on"]'))
for (WebElement element: allElements) {
      text_item.add(allElements.getText())
}
```

you should have [48630 , 49928]